# Accessing Classes from another class

Tags: java, class, jvm

Assuming I am not using any IDE to build/run my Java codes. But using notepad and command prompt to do the compilation and running.

Can I safely assume that: as long as I place my class files within the same folder, they will **always** be able to "see" each other **even** **without stating the package**?

I came from another link with similar question title: [Accessing other class files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357250/accessing-other-class-files-in-java)
but it is asking a different thing and the replies given are in context of having a IDE, and using IDE to change CLASSPATH.

What I intends to find out here is the behaviour of JVM without an IDE.

**QUE:** Can I safely assume classes can **ALWAYS** "see" each other by just placing them in the same folder?

Comment: No. You cannot safely assume that and import(s) are not optional.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch which import(s) are you referring to? thanks

Comment: The ones in your question; *even without stating the package?*

Comment: since he uses the default package and a class with private modifier will not compile (as class per file) he is fine.

Comment: There are some restrictions like private nested classes, but these you would not see with an import statement as well.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Because those files I wrote with notepad, I did not import anything, but it still works fine. Anyway if I state the package name, can I safely assume the classes can see each other?

Comment: you can. since your classes are either "public class" or "class" (which is package visibility) and since the are all in one package (folder) you are just fine.

Comment: @ManuelM. So it is guaranteed that classes can see one another so long as they are in same folder? Hope you can give a confirmation to this :)

Comment: if you dont have any external dependencies or override any java classes this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some food for your thoughts :-)

Let's suppose we have two versions of the same file

version 1

```
package mypack;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(1);
    }

}
```

version 2

```
package mypack;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(2);
    }

}
```

compile version 2 like this

```
[leoks@x ~]$ javac mypack/MyClass.java
[leoks@x ~]$ java mypack.MyClass
2
```

and then create a jar with version 1 and save it as "myjar.jar"

now try

```
[leoks@x ~]$ java -cp myjar.jar:. mypack.MyClass
1

[leoks@x ~]$ java -cp .:myjar.jar mypack.MyClass
2
```

As you can see, the classloader does not care. It just takes the first class and ignores the second one.

So it's not a matter of **folders**. It's a matter of **packages**. The JVM deals with packages, which can be in the directory organization or inside the jar.

Comment: What about cases when there is no package stated in the java files? Hope you can cover that. Thank you..

Comment: When you don't state a package, your class lives in the "default package", which is just another package (without a name). Leo's example would still behave the same if there were no package declarations anywhere.

Comment: you are right but how would you have both classes in one folder? this is a bit abstract, since the one of the class files would overwrite the other one while copying them into one folder. your scenario is only possible through the help of jar files.

Comment: @user3437460: maybe you should give more details on the surrounding scenario and what you need this for / what is the java environment etc.